# Weird behavior of urlrewriting in MVC3 with razor viewengine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a project which adopted ASP.NET MVC3(Razor) tech.
Now, I have a controller below:

```
public class Home: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Result(string id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
}
```

and I have set MapRoute as below:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Home_result",
    "Home/Result/{id}",
    new { controller="Home", action = "Result"}
);
```

and it was suposed to display a View which named "Result" when I typed the url http://domain.com/Home/Result/abc123 in the browser. However it didn't.
Instead it gave me an exception below:

```
The view 'Result' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/abc123.cshtml
~/Views/Home/abc123.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/abc123.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/abc123.vbhtml
```

It is strange isn't it?
Can anyone help me to figure out what mistakes I've made?

Comment: remove that route. what's the point of it? the default route will suffice in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return View(id);
```

Returns a view with the name of ID's value (.cshtml), not the view with the name result.cshtml.  **I think this is because Id is a string.**  Are you trying to pass the id to the view?

To return the view matching the name of your controller's action simply use

```
return View();
```

If you want to pass that value to the view, for what ever crazy reason, using the viewbag is the easiest way since the string id is being used to declare a view name.

```
ViewBag.ID = id;
return View();
```

Then in the view just use the value you stored.  And yes Razor HTML encodes by default.

```
@ViewBag.ID
```